# MPD problems - no music showing

Tags: linux, arch, mpd

When I want to run ncmpcpp I saw no music showing up. My mpd service (user level) is running without problems, but when I run it manually, verbose I get this output.

```
mpd --verbose --stdout --no-daemon
config_file: loading file /home/woutd/.config/mpd/mpd.conf
libsamplerate: libsamplerate converter 'Fastest Sinc Interpolator'
vorbis: Xiph.Org libVorbis 1.3.7
opus: libopus 1.3.1
sndfile: libsndfile-1.2.0
hybrid_dsd: The Hybrid DSD decoder is disabled because it was not explicitly enabled
simple_db: reading DB
input: Input plugin 'qobuz' is not configured: No Qobuz app_id configured
curl: version 7.87.0
curl: with OpenSSL/3.0.7
state_file: Loading state file /home/woutd/.mpd/mpdstate
event: RTIOThread could not get realtime scheduling, continuing anyway: sched_setscheduler failed: Operation not permitted
client: [0] opened from 127.0.0.1:42672
client: [0] process command "idle"
client: [0] command returned 1
client: [0] process command "idle"
client: [0] command returned 1
client: [0] process command "currentsong"
client: [0] command returned 0
client: [0] process command "idle"
client: [0] command returned 1
client: [0] process command "idle"
client: [0] command returned 1
client: [0] process command "idle"
client: [0] command returned 1
client: [0] process command "idle"
client: [0] command returned 1
client: [0] process command "idle"
client: [0] command returned 1
client: [0] process command "idle"
client: [0] command returned 1
client: [0] process command "idle"
client: [0] command returned 1
client: [0] process command "idle"
client: [0] command returned 1
client: [0] process command "idle"
client: [0] command returned 1
client: [0] process command "idle"
client: [0] command returned 1
^Cstate_file: Saving state file /home/woutd/.mpd/mpdstate
fifo_output: Removing FIFO "/tmp/mpd.fifo"
```

Anyone that can help??? I'd really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

**Update database:**

Inside ncmpcpp, press <kbd>u</kbd> to update.

**Add music to the playlist:**

Inside ncmpcpp, press <kbd>2</kbd> to the `Browse` section, then <kbd>Space</kbd> or <kbd>a</kbd> to add, press <kbd>1</kbd> to go back to the `Playlist` section.